# Python: How to check an XML file every x minutes for new entries, but not alert on previously alerted entries

Tags: python

I'm using urllib2 and ElementTree to monitor an XML file for new entries, and [Pushover](https://pushover.net/) to send push notifications every time a new entry is detected. Entries exist in the XML file for anywhere from 30 min to 4 hours. The script runs every 5 minutes. What is the best way to make the script only alert me on the **new** entires and not the same entries every 5 minutes?

Comment: Can you keep a record of which entries have corresponding alerts, and delete the entries from the "already alerted" list when they are no longer in the file to keep it from growing indefinitely?

Comment: A log seems like the easiest answer. I guess I was hoping for something a little more... elegant :P Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't see a way around it. Somewhere, you **have** to store whether the entry notification has already gone out. If yoou're allowed to modify the file, I supposed you could make it an XML element/attribute instead.

Comment: Would hashing work here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252576/how-to-check-if-the-value-on-a-website-has-changed

Answer (score 0):

Are the entries associated with a timestamp such that the new entries will always have timestamps later than the old entries each time the file is updated? If so, just keep the timestamp of the last entry you pushed, and as you parse the XML file, push anything newer and discard anything older.

If not, Python has pretty decent set manipulation algorithms, so I'd try this: keep a `set` of entries that have been pushed already.

```
already_pushed = set()
```

Each time your script runs, do this:

1. make another `set` of the entries from the file

   ```
   from_file = parse_file()
   ```
2. "subtract" (set difference) the set of already-pushed entries

   ```
   new_entries = from_file - already_pushed
   ```
3. push the new entries

   ```
   push_all(new_entries)
   ```
4. go through the original set and prune anything older than 4 hours + 5 minutes

   ```
   cutoff = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=4, minutes=5) # I forget the syntax
   already_pushed = set(e for e in already_pushed if e.timestamp > cutoff)
   ```
5. add in the newly pushed entries

   ```
   already_pushed += new_entries
   ```

Since you're only running this every five minutes, unless you have an astronomically large number of entries in the file, it should be plenty fast enough.

If efficiency were a concern, you could probably make a better algorithm by keeping a sorted (by timestamp) list of entries already pushed, parsing the file into a similarly sorted list of entries, and running a merge algorithm that processes an entry from one list or the other, pushing and keeping or discarding it as appropriate. But the efficiency gain you'd get from using a better algorithm would probably be more than outweighed by the efficiency loss from implementing the whole thing in Python. You'd probably have to use C or C++ to actually get better performance in that case.