# Why is my R webscraper slower than webmonitor apps?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Every day around 12:30 the Swiss government publishes corona data on a website. I run a scraper that is supposed to notify a slack-channel as soon as the numbers are published.
However, every day my scraper is a few minutes slower than the webmonitor apps my colleagues use. I don't know how to make it even faster.
At this point it runs on a repeat loop that scrapes the website every 0-2 seconds and I start it around 11:00 with a Linux crontab. Any suggestions?

```
#Packages

if (!require('lubridate')) {install.packages('lubridate')};library('lubridate')
if (!require('magrittr')) {install.packages('magrittr')};library('magrittr')
if (!require('rvest')) {install.packages('rvest')};library('rvest')
if (!require('slackr')) {install.packages('slackr')};library('slackr')
if (!require('XML')) {install.packages('XML')};library('XML')


#Basics
linux <- "/home/pi/R/projects"
setwd(linux)
slackr_setup(config_file = ".coronapush")
y <- 1

#scraping
bag_alt <- xml2::read_html('https://www.bag.admin.ch/bag/de/home/krankheiten/ausbrueche-epidemien-pandemien/aktuelle-ausbrueche-epidemien/novel-cov/situation-schweiz-und-international.html')
anzahl_faelle_alt <- bag_alt %>% 
  html_nodes('#2030838475+ .mod-table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)') %>% 
  html_text()
anzahl_faelle_alt <- gsub("[[:space:]]", "", anzahl_faelle_alt) %>%
  as.integer()
anzahl_tote_alt <- bag_alt %>%
  html_nodes('#2030838475+ .mod-table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2)') %>% 
  html_text()
anzahl_tote_alt <- gsub("[[:space:]]", "", anzahl_tote_alt) %>%
  as.integer()
anzahl_tests_alt <- bag_alt %>%
  html_nodes('tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2)')%>%
  html_text()
anzahl_tests_alt <- gsub("[[:space:]]", "", anzahl_tests_alt) %>%
  as.integer()

#prepare loop
tests_gemacht <- F
faelle_gemacht <- F
tote_gemacht <- F
y <- 1

#Loop

repeat {
  bag_neu <- xml2::read_html('https://www.bag.admin.ch/bag/de/home/krankheiten/ausbrueche-epidemien-pandemien/aktuelle-ausbrueche-epidemien/novel-cov/situation-schweiz-und-international.html')  
    anzahl_faelle_neu <- bag_neu %>% 
      html_nodes('#2030838475+ .mod-table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)') %>% 
      html_text() 
    anzahl_faelle_neu <- gsub("[[:space:]]", "", anzahl_faelle_neu) %>%
      as.integer()
    
    anzahl_tote_neu <- bag_neu %>%
      html_nodes('#2030838475+ .mod-table tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2)') %>% 
      html_text() 
    anzahl_tote_neu <- gsub("[[:space:]]", "", anzahl_tote_neu) %>%
      as.integer()

    anzahl_tests_neu <- bag_neu %>%
      html_nodes('tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(2)')%>%
      html_text()
    anzahl_tests_neu <- gsub("[[:space:]]", "", anzahl_tests_neu) %>%
      as.integer()
    
    if(anzahl_faelle_alt != anzahl_faelle_neu) {
      ansteckungen <- paste0("Neue BAG-Zahlen: ", anzahl_faelle_neu, " Ansteckungen,")
      slackr_bot(ansteckungen)
      faelle_gemacht <- T
      }
    if(anzahl_tests_alt != anzahl_tests_neu) { 
      anzahl_tests_neu_formatiert <- format(anzahl_tests_neu, big.mark = "'")
      tests <- paste0(anzahl_tests_neu_formatiert, " Tests")
        slackr_bot(tests)
        tests_gemacht <- T
        }
   
    if(tests_gemacht == T && faelle_gemacht == T) {
      positivitaet <- anzahl_faelle_neu/anzahl_tests_neu*100
      positivitaet<-  round(positivitaet,1) %>%
        as.character()
      positivitaet <- paste0(positivitaet, "% Positivität")
      slackr_bot(positivitaet)
    }
    if(anzahl_tote_alt != anzahl_tote_neu) { 
      tote <- paste0(anzahl_tote_neu, " Tote")
      slackr_bot(tote)
      tote_gemacht <- T
    }
    
    if(tests_gemacht == T && faelle_gemacht == T && tote_gemacht == F){
      tote <- paste0(anzahl_tote_neu, " Tote")
      slackr_bot(tote)
      tote_gemacht <- T
    }
y <-y+1    
if (faelle_gemacht == T && tote_gemacht == T && tests_gemacht == T){
  quit()
}
if (y == 15000){
  quit()
}
x <- runif(1,0,2)
Sys.sleep(x)
print(y)
}
```

Comment: It seems like you do all the scraping and all the calculations every single try. Is there one things you could quickly look at to see if things have changed, and if not, stop calculating and wait for the next iteration? Maybe move the sleep to the top of the loop, and then the first thing the loop checks is the date on the website, and if the new date is not found immediate go to `next`.

Comment: Or, you could take inspiration [from some of the answers to this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11254089/903061) to check if there have been any changes by looking at the headers, or hashing the content, checking the total length, etc.

Comment: But, overall, if your script is several *minutes* slower than the webmonitor apps, it must be taking several minutes to run... I would suggest profiling or introducing a little timestamp logging to see what the slow parts are.

Comment: I'll check that today, thx. Maybe I can change from rvest to httr and GET the version date of the page.